# strongest sound and complete logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

What is the strongest sound and complete logic (with respect to its standard semantics)?  As first pass, I mean that L* is stronger than L when what L proves is proper subset of what L* proves.  (Clearly, one would need a way to identify sentences in across the languages of L and L* in order for this to make sense.  I assume that there is a useful way to do this.)  I know of Lindström's theorem.  But perhaps there are sound and complete logics that do not have the compactness and Löwenheim–Skolem properties?  What is motivating my question is why we have implicitly taken first-order classical logic to be canonical in the sense that a proof is valid just in case there is a formal first-order classical surrogate in, say, ZFC.

Comment: If a logic is complete, you can't get a stronger logic.

Comment: Thanks.  But isn't intuitionistic logic complete, though classical logic is stronger?

Comment: (Another version of the question: why can't one expand the language of first-order logic and retain soundness and completeness?)

Comment: The *completeness* in soundness/completeness refers to a relationship between a derivability relation ⊢ (logic) and entailment relation (semantics) ⊨ defined on the *same* set of formulas. As soon as you expand the logical language with new connectives and quantifiers, you change the set of formulas: it no longer makes sense to talk about completeness with respect to ⊨, and does not not make sense to talk about *retaining* soundness and completeness w.r.t. the old semantics. To account for the new formulas, you need to devise a new semantics as well.

Comment: @davidp depends, I guess, on what you mean by completeness. I was taking for completeness the idea that all statements in the logic can either be proved or disproved.

Comment: Thank you.  Z.A.K., are you saying that there is no useful sense in which classical logic is stronger than intuitionistic logic, because the standard semantics with respect to which they are complete are different?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You're confused about the two meanings of completeness in logic. A *theory* $T$ is complete if $T\vdash \varphi$ or $T\vdash \lnot \varphi$ for all sentences $\varphi$. A *logic* (which comes with notions of provability $\vdash$ and semantic entailment $\models$) is complete if $\models \varphi$ implies $\vdash \varphi$ for all sentences $\varphi$.

Comment: Thanks, Alex.  I think I understand all of that.  My thought was that intuitionistic logic (with respect to the Kripke semantics) is complete in that there is a proof of every validity.  Likewise, (any typical proof system for) classical logic is complete (with respect to the Tarskian semantics).  But isn't there still a useful sense in which classical logic is stronger?  It has more validities (and, thus, theorems).

Comment: @davidp My comment was addressed to Thomas Andrews. I agree with you that classical logic is *syntactically* stronger than intuitionistic logic (it proves more theorems). It doesn't make sense to say that it is *semantically* stronger, since they have different semantics. Ok, but on the syntactic side it's clear that there's no strongest logic, as long as you're allowed to introduce new syntactic constructions. You can always introduce some new syntactic construction and give it some trivial semantics, and introduce corresponding proof rules to get completeness. Voila: a stronger logic.

Comment: Thanks, Alex.  Just to confirm: Lindström's theorem guarantees that classical logic is the strongest logic satisfying the compactness and Löwenheim–Skolem properties.  But you are saying that it does not follow that it is the strongest logic that is merely sound and complete (for its semantics).  Moreover, there is no strongest such logic.  Is that right?